# What is the purpose of 多 in 你多与别人就此事沟通?

Tags: translation, difference

I have a sentence with a given translation, as follows:

你多与别人就此事沟通。 = You communicate with other people.

Why is 多 put into this sentence, it is not mentioned in the translation. 
What would be the difference between the given sentence and the same sentence without the 多?

你**多**与别人就此事沟通    <> 你与别人就此事沟通  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a polite way to make suggestions, e.g.

```
我建议你多运动。
I suggest you to do sports/exercises.
```

or

```
请你多指教。
Please give some guidance/opinion.
```

So I guess, a more proper translation of you example would be: 'You should contact other people about this issue.'

Comment: Is this similar to english "better", like in : you better go and apologize V.S. you go and apologize ?

Comment: Not exactly, I guess. Wang Dingwei will give you a better picture of it, my guess is that you can simply think of this 多 as "do more if you are already doing it, or do if you don't do it at all". You catch a cold and a friend says to you: 你多喝茶！ Drink (more) tea! [depending on if you are actually already a regular tea drinker or don't drink tea at all]

Comment: yo, that is quiet helpful!

Answer (score 0):

你多与别人就此事沟通 means you should take more attention to talk with others.

你与别人就此事沟通 means you should talk to others.

Answer (score 0):

Means "more often" or "it's better to do sth"